# Form submit handler never called

Tags: 8, forms

I'm trying to process my custom form.  However, code inside the submitForm function is never called.  I have not seen any solutions, yet for getting Drupal 8's submitForm to be called.

```
namespace Drupal\archive\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

class DateForm extends FormBase
{
    public function getFormId() { return 'archive_dateform'; }

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form['#action'] = Url::fromRoute('archive.dateform')->toString();

        $form['type'] = [
            '#type' => 'hidden',
            '#value' => $form_state->get('type')
        ];

        $form['year'] = [
            '#title'         => 'Year',
            '#type'          => 'number',
            '#size'          => 4,
            '#step'          => 1,
            '#default_value' => $form_state->get('year'),
        ];

        $options = [];
        for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) { $options[$i] = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10)); }
        $form['month'] = [
            '#title'         => 'Month',
            '#type'          => 'select',
            '#options'       => $options,
            '#default_value' => $form_state->get('month'),
            '#empty_option'  => 'All',
            '#empty_value'   => 0
        ];

        $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
        $form['actions']['submit'] = [
            '#type'        => 'submit',
            '#value'       => 'Search',
            '#button_type' => 'primary'
        ];
        return $form;
    }

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $type = $form_state->get('type');
        if (!$type) {
            $form_state->setErrorByName('type', 'Missing Type');
        }
    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        echo "submitForm\n";
        exit();
        $type = $form_state->get('type');

        $year = (int)$form_state->get('year');
        if (!$year) { $year = (int)date('Y'); }
        $params = ['year'=>$year];

        $month = (int)$form_state->get('month');
        if ($month) { $params['month'] = $month; }

        $form_state->setRedirect("archive.$type", $params);
        return;
    }
}
```

And using from a controller

```
namespace Drupal\archive\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormState;

class ArchiveController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function archive($type, $year, $month, $day)
    {
        $year  = (int)$year;
        $month = (int)$month;
        $day   = (int)$day;

        if (!$year) { $year = (int)date('Y'); }

        if (!$month) {
            $date = "$year-01-01";
            $period = new \DateInterval('P1Y1D');
        }
        else {
            if (!$day) {
                $date   = "$year-$month-01";
                $period = new \DateInterval('P1M1D');
            }
            else {
                $date   = "$year-$month-$day";
                $period = new \DateInterval('P1D');
            }
        }
        $start = new \DateTime($date);
        $end   = new \DateTime($date);
        $end->add($period);

        $manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
        $query   = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->condition('type',    $type)
                ->condition('created', $start->format('U'), '>=')
                ->condition('created', $end  ->format('U'), '<')
                ->condition('status',  1);

        $form_state = new FormState();
        $form_state->set('type',  $type);
        $form_state->set('year',  $year);
        $form_state->set('month', $month);
        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->buildForm('Drupal\archive\Form\DateForm', $form_state);

        return [
            '#theme'   => 'archive_results',
            '#year'    => $year,
            '#start'   => $start,
            '#form'    => $form,
            '#results' => $manager->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple(
                            $manager->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($query->execute()),
                            'teaser'
                        )
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're determining that the submit handlers is not reached because of your echo statement, that won't work. Change it to `drupal_set_message("submit");` and remove the call to exit, and you will likely see the submit handler is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your validation fails because you need to

```
$form_state->setValue('type',  $type);
```

in your controller instead of

```
$form_state->set('type',  $type);
```

Comment: Calling form_state->setValue() results in the fields not being rendered with those values.  I'm not sure setValue() works that way.

Comment: Did you also change '#default_value' => $form_state->get('year') to getValue() in your Form class? Think it's supposed to work that way.

Comment: Okay, I think that is, a big part of my problem.  I am now calling ->getValue() and ->setValue(), instead of just plain ->get() and ->set().

The validate() and submitForm() functions are, in fact, being called now.  Now I just have to figure out why the values are not there when I call $form_state->getValue('type') from inside the validate() and submitForm() functions.  (but that sounds like a topic for another question.)

Comment: The type field is now coming across as well.  I had to use #default_value, instead of #value.

    $form['type'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#default_value' => $form_state->getValue('type')
    ];


I had thought that #default_value was only for non-hidden fields.  Turns out, I was wrong (as I often am).

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the form in #form. Drupal doesn't process things inside #attributes. That means your form isn't really a form and a lot of the required processing isn't happening.

You need to define your template as accepting a render element, and then e.g. print it as elements.form and set as just 'form' => $form.

Comment: hey @Berdir how can I pass a form outside of #attributes?
So I have a custom module, with a admin_settings_form and I need to load a twig file with this form and some other info.
On my_module.form I have submitForm() function, but this is not working when I load a twig file, also I am passing form inside attributes like this return [
      '#theme' => 'admin_form',
      '#teste' => $form,
    ];
My form appear as expected but when I click submit nothing happen, tried to remove '#' but no luck. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post but it help me someway, so I will leave my answear, hope it will help someone.

I had same problem, my submit never called.

I pass my form as @Berdir said, like this:

MYMODULE.module file.

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'admin_form' => [
      'template' => 'admin-form',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ],
  ];
}
```

The on my form.php (MYMODULE/scr/Form/form.php) inside buildForm function

```
$form['simulator_values']['connection_services'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#maxlength' => 140,
  '#default_value' => $config->get('connection_services'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
];

$form['actions'] = [
  '#type' => 'actions'
];

$form['actions']['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit ss')
];

return [
  '#theme' => 'admin_form',
  'render element' => $form,
];
```

Finally on twig side have to build form like this

```
<form {{ attributes }}>
  {{ form.form_build_id }}
  {{ form.form_token }}
  {{ form.form_id }}
  {{ form['render element'].advanced_info }}
  {{ form['render element'].actions.submit }}
</form>
```

Without form_build_id, form_token and form_id the submit button won't work.

As far I understood drupal need those information about the form to process everything on the right way, because you can have multiple forms on the same page.